# What primal path should I take at 3rd level as a Half-Orc Barbarian?

Tags: dnd-5e, barbarian, half-orc

I really can't decide what primal path to take. I hesitate between Path of the Totem Warrior and Path of the Ancestral Guardian.

And I would be really happy if you can give me advice because I am really inexperienced in D&D and this is my first time playing. I like more second, but my friends are saying me to take the first one, but they are all also as inexperienced as I and I would want to hear advice of some more experienced.

The party consists of Paladin, Rogue, Cleric, Warlock and me(Barbarian).

Comment: Hi Pakk, I've removed the huge copy & paste since the experts involved would be assumed to already have access to that material & be able to check on those rages. However, I'm temporarily putting this on hold: either option is a viable option in various circumstances. What are you looking to do with your barbarian? Once we have some more information about what's going on for you, we can reopen this and get to answering.

Comment: copy and paste of copyrighted material to the extent that you did is not consistent with *fair use*.  The SE network of sites adheres to *fair use* to avoid legal trouble.  Anyone with enough expertise to answer this question will be familiar with the material.  Plus, you are  not choosing a rage, you are choosing a sub class or archetype. Rage is a feature of all barbarian sub classes/archetypes.  It is technically called a "primal path."

Comment: What are the other players playing: what other classes are in your group?(please list them; fighter? Paladin? Wizard? Druid?  how many others and what class are they playing?

Comment: Okay. There are 5 of us: Paladin, Rogue, Cleric, Warlock  and me

Comment: @Pakk To remove the hold, edit the question to provide a specific goal or some criteria for the character so there can be a "right" answer